# HAProxy get username associated with Basic Auth

Tags: basic-authentication, haproxy

I am currently using HAProxy's `http-request auth` operation to conditionally restrict access to resources. I would like to go on to add the username associated with a successful authorisation to the headers of the request being passed to the backend, emulating the Apache environment variable `HTTP_AUTH_USER`.

I am able to get the group associated with the operation by way of `http_auth_group` but would much rather have the username.

I appreciate I could move this operation to the web servers but I would rather not administer a small number usernames and passwords on 10s of machines when I can do it in 2 places via the proxy.

Comment: The [`http_auth_group` fetch](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-http_auth_group) takes the group as its argument.  According the documentation, it returns the username.  Have you tried using this fetch in conjunction with `http-request set-header`?

Comment: Michael, `http-request add-header X-Username %[http_auth_group(GROUP_NAME)]` appears to have done the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`http_auth_group` layer 7 sample fetch](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-http_auth_group) is a little bit confusingly named at first glance, with the word "group" appearing in it, implying that it returns the group.  In fact, it takes the group as its argument and returns no value unless the request has been authenticate with the credentials of a member of the specified group... in which case, it returns the username.

So it has two purposes: testing its truthiness to determine whether any member of the group has authenticated the request, or extracting the username.  So...

```
http-request set-header X-Username %[http_auth_group(GROUP_NAME)]
```

...will *remove* any `X-Username:` header (case-insensitive) in the incoming request (if already present), and populate a new `X-Usernane:` header with the username of the authenticated user, or a blank value otherwise (if your config allows anonymous requests).

It's important to use `set-header`, **not** `add-header`, because adding the header will not remove any matching header in the incoming request, which presents a security risk.  Always set unless you have a specific reason to add, instead.

Comment: I have a `del-header` in the config at the moment as there are some other routes (main IP addresses) by which the traffic can arrive and the backend takes different actions accordingly. Up-vote, though, as you make an excellent point about the security risks.